# Force all other codes to not execute until UserForm has finished its job

Tags: vba, excel, events, userform

I have a problem in VBA, the problem goes like this:

I have a routine that triggers a userform whenever a given condition is met. This will show the userform. I noticed that while the userform is shown, other part of my program still runs while the current routine (that triggers the userform) waits.

I am looking for a way to prevent other code/routines to run while the userform is open. I am not providing examples of my code because it is bundled up with APIs, so please consider that as my excuse.

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the userform in Modal mode and code execution following the Show method will be halted until the form is closed.

```
MyUserForm.Show vbModal
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, I actually used this before but it did not work. I realized that the sub routine that calls the userform is put on hold either way, but other codes in the program are running. So I just had to shift the order to fix the problem!